# Using jQuery for avoid form action caught error

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I want to save data standard name to database using jQuery with not required form `th:action` and redirection.

I tried with this but caught error.

If you know the reason for this error please explain here.

**Thymeleaf code**

```
<form action="#"  >
<table>
<h1>Create Standard</h1>
<tr>
<td>Standard Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" th:value="${standardName}" placeholder="Enter Standard Name" required="required"id="std" name="stdName"/></td></tr>
<td><input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" id="savebutton" name="save" /></td>
</table>
</form>
```

I am using jQuery because of the redirect and form actions are not working here. That's my requirement, so I use jQuery.

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#savebutton").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : "/saveStandards.html ",
            data : ({
                std : standardName //this standardName not defined that is the error 
            })

    });

  });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/saveStandards.html"))
  @ResponseBody
  def saveStandards(@RequestParam std:String) {
  var standard:Standard=new Standard
    standard.setCreatedDate(new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime))
    standardService.addStandard(standard)
    println("*****inside controller*****"+std+"****last***")//here std is not printing because of the value not catch @ here
```

}

**error caught:**

Uncaught ReferenceError: standardName is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you do not have a variable declared with name `standardName`, you can fix as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#savebutton").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "/learnware/saveStandards.html ",
            data : ({
                std : $('#std').val()
            })

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) occured